# XmlSeeAlso issue deployment of apache cxf to weblogic server in java 1.5 environment

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, classpath, cxf

I am getting this error when i try to run an ant script with jdk 1.5 minor version 14 .  I do have all the libraries in the ant script - but still i am getting this error. Any thoughts. Any pointers will be of great help.

```
    ClientConfiguration.java:123: cannot access javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso
    [javac] file javax\xml\bind\annotation\XmlSeeAlso.class not found
    [javac]             config.getHttpConduit().getClient().setConnectionTimeout(timeOut);
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 1 error

      BUILD FAILED
```

List of dependent libraries which i added

```
   06/06/2013  10:58            62,983 activation-1.1.jar
   08/07/2013  17:09         1,015,426 cxf-api-2.6.8.jar
   08/07/2013  17:09            38,114 cxf-rt-bindings-xml-2.6.8.jar
   08/07/2013  17:09           371,239 cxf-rt-core-2.6.8.jar
   08/07/2013  18:32           115,654 cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.6.8.jar
   08/07/2013  20:03            33,325 cxf-rt-features-clustering-2.6.8.jar
   08/07/2013  17:09           513,121 cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.6.8.jar
   08/07/2013  17:09            71,201 cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers-2.6.8.jar
   08/07/2013  17:09            87,096 cxf-rt-rs-extension-search-2.6.8.jar
   08/07/2013  17:09           223,028 cxf-rt-transports-http-2.6.8.jar

   08/07/2013  17:47            47,465 geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.1.jar
   08/07/2013  17:47            12,452 geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar
   08/07/2013  16:22           223,298 geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar
   08/07/2013  17:47            28,804 geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
   08/07/2013  17:53            33,525 jackson-annotations-2.0.2.jar
   08/07/2013  17:53           193,693 jackson-core-2.0.2.jar
   08/07/2013  17:53           847,121 jackson-databind-2.0.2.jar
   08/07/2013  17:53            26,098 jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.0.2.jar
   08/07/2013  17:53            31,123 jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.0.2.jar
   26/06/2013  18:27            73,081 jaxb-api-2.0.jar
   08/07/2013  18:23           786,408 jaxb-impl-2.0.1.jar
   08/07/2013  18:32         3,476,096 jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.1.jar
   26/06/2013  18:27            49,672 jsr173_api-1.0.jar
   08/07/2013  17:09            46,367 jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
   06/06/2013  11:31            23,346 stax-api-1.0-2.jar
   08/07/2013  16:22           182,112 stax2-api-3.1.1.jar
   08/07/2013  16:22           482,245 woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0.jar
   08/07/2013  16:22           186,758 wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar
   08/07/2013  16:22           162,818 xmlschema-core-2.0.3.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [XmlSeeAlso Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html) the annotation exists since JAXB **2.1** - you're using JABX **2.0.1**, upgrade to 2.1 or higher and it should work.

Comment: Just now noticed that the project build xml already has jaxb-api-2.0.jar and jaxb-api.jar as dependencies for some of the code. Can these jaxb-api.jar , jaxb-api-2.1.jar , jaxb-api-2.0.jar co-exist ? Project is updated by many parties so facing a big issue .

Comment: I tried removing the jaxb-api 2.0  from the build compile library and i am getting this error now -  [javac] An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.5.0_14). Please file a
bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  af
ter checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the followi
ng diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
    [javac] com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: file javax\xml\bi
nd\annotation\XmlRootElement.class not found

Comment: Looks like you're missing the XmlRootElement annotation (that exists since JAXB 2.0) so it does not look like you have all API jars for JAXB 2.1 - you should considerer analyzing which jaxb jars you have in your classpath and which classes/interfaces are contained within them - or maybe removing all of them and restarting from scratch

Comment: Thanks! But its tough to check the dependencies right from scratch ! Now things are getting complex after adding JAXB 2.1 - can apache CXF work with jaxb api 2.0 version . (well this version is already present in my main project build.xml).

Comment: Is there any way to set the timeout to CXF client without changing the version of JAXB    config.getHttpConduit().getClient().setConnectionTimeout ???

Comment: Yes, see http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Turn-off-all-timeouts-with-WebClient-in-JAX-RS-td3364696.html for an example

Comment: Thanks I got it resolved. Well in the classpath - i changed the order and it worked ! Now version 2 and 2.1 reside together without any issues.